# Selecting a id from a pivot table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Trying to make a messaging system, similar to FB, people can message more than one person, when they do it creates a row for the user with the conversation id and user_id in conversation_user.

```
create table conversations(
  id int
);
create table users(
  id int,
  name text
);
create table conversations_users(
  user_id int,
  conversation_id int
);
create table conversations_reply(
  id int,
  user_id int,
  body text,
  conversation_id int
);
```

I want to select the last 10 conversation that user_id 1 is a participant in and select the last post of that conversation. How would I go about doing this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb0075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find with subquery each `conversation_id` for `user_id` from table `conversations_users` and use `left join` for get one reply for each `conversation_id` from `conversation_reply` table (see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35a72a/4) example and code below)

```
select cp1.* from conversations_reply cp1 
left join conversations_reply cp2 
  on (cp1.conversation_id = cp2.conversation_id AND cp1.id < cp2.id)
where cp2.id is NULL and
  cp1.conversation_id in (
    select conversation_id from conversations_users where user_id = 4
  ) 
order by cp1.id desc limit 10;
```

Output will be

```
+---+-------+--------+---------------+
|id |user_id|body    |conversation_id|
+---+-------+--------+---------------+
|9  |      4| message|              4|
|8  |      4| message|              3|
|7  |      1| message|              1|
|6  |      4| message|              2|
+---+-------+--------+---------------+
```